# Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting this error trying to build a project opened as file => open web site.

This is not an MVC application and another suggestion I found online suggest deleting the content of the obj directory. I don't have an obj directory, not in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\home.sln (2) nor in the web site directory.

Using Visual studio express 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem once when I added `Combress` in one of my application. Actually it was adding `xmlns` attribute in the tags of web.config file. To resolve that issue I just removed the `xmlns` attributes from tags in web.config file.

So, This can be easily sorted by removing the `xmlns=""` attribute from the web.config or any other affected files.

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, thank you for your reply. It's actually the web.config from the server. Not sure why it wouldn't build but under website => startup options I've selected not to build and it seems to work. I've never worked with website projects so stuggling to get it to work.

Comment: If you want to look into the file on server, you can search the path inside `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`. If you want to get into details of the issue please look to this article: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33199

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev, there doesn't seem to be any xmlns in any of the web.config files under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*\CONFIG